# my variable cannot be resolved into a type in java

Tags: java, types, get, set

It keeps saying that 'Cow' cannot be resolved to a type. I am new at java and would like some help!

```
public class UnoMas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cow c;
        c = new Cow("Gerard, Golgari Lich Lord");
        c.setPower(0);
        c.setToughness(0);
        speakToTheGolgari(c);
        System.out.println(c.getPower);
        System.out.println(c.getToughness);
    }

    public static void speakToTheGolgari(Cow d) {
        d.setPower(d.getPower() + 2);
        d.setToughness(d.getToughness() + 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a "Cow" class ? Cow.java ?

Comment: well you need a class named Cow to be able to declare an object of that type.

Comment: When you initialise it you must give it a type like Cow c = new Cow(rest here); assuming you have a cow class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is a custom class that you're meant to create?
Since you're new to Java I'm also assuming that you didn't know that you're supposed to create it?

In any event create your 'Cow' class as per below (feel free to remove redundant constructors):

```
public class Cow {
    private String name;
    private int power;
    private int toughness;

    public Cow() {
    }

    public Cow(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.power = power;
        this.toughness = toughness;
    }

    public Cow(String name, int power) {
        this.name = name;
        this.power = power;
        this.toughness = toughness;
    }

    public Cow(String name, int power, int toughness) {
        this.name = name;
        this.power = power;
        this.toughness = toughness;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public void setPower(int power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

    public int getToughness() {
        return toughness;
    }

    public void setToughness(int toughness) {
        this.toughness = toughness;
    }
}
```